# Can I pickle sklearn model after restart notebook kernel?

Tags: python, serialization, persistence, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I trained a machine learning model using sklearn in a jupyter notebook which took many hours.

Next, i shutdown the notebook, but the server is still running locally.

Can I just restart the notebook and pickle the model or is it too late?

Comment: I believe shutting down the notebook clears all the state from that notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too late. If you shut a Notebook down. it clears the state unless you store the variables -
[relevant documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html)